# How to generate a 1d array with very large size

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For instance I want to generate a 1d array with size of 1 trillion

```
A = np.arange(1000000000000,dtype='float')
```

whenever I run this code I get

```
Memory error
```

is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need an array of such a large size? If you add more information about your problem you might get an answer that takes a completly different approach to the problem instead.

Comment: This depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It overflows the memory

Comment: @JakobVinkas we were asked to code an efficient method to get the square root of each element of an array if we are dealing with very large size. it is one of the req to use a 1 trillion sized array

Comment: As a general rule will not generate an array that large unless you have the virtual address space to store it. If you were asking for **slightly** too much, then the answer might be to close other programs, or to configure some disk to use as swap space, or even to add some more physical RAM to your machine.   However, running out of memory also suggests that you need to refactor your algorithm to use smaller arrays.  In this case you are asking for I think 8 terabytes (might be 4TB), and it is extremely unlikely that you will be able to provide that.  Refactor the code.

Comment: What for? You should use a generator.

Comment: A generator that wrote the results to disk would at least prevent memory issues, although you may then get some disk space issues... What requirements do you have for the output?

Comment: @IainShelvington an array of the square root of each element

Answer (score 0):

Well you seem to have a problem that your computer can simply not handle. There is simply not enough RAM memory. If you instead change the datatype to int you can clearly see the difference in storing different data types in the memory:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.arange(1000000000000,dtype='float')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.28 TiB for an array with shape (1000000000000,) and data type float64
>>> A = np.arange(1000000000000,dtype='int')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.64 TiB for an array with shape (1000000000000,) and data type int32
```

A solution would be to split up the array into subarrays before the problem even begins but you would still not be able to present the result in a single array since it would need to be of the original trillion size.